# Sparse indexing and dense clustering indexing?

Tags: database

I was reading about indexing. There I found that sparse indexing means for each unique value there would be only one entry in the index file and for dense indexing, there would be an entry in the index file for each search key in the data file. But I am super confused with some of the concepts.

1. Is cluster index is sparse or dense.
2. Is there any difference between sparse index and dense clustering index

Because in the given image I think the example is a sparse index but it is written that it is an example of dense clustering index. The image is from book Silberschatz.

[image]

Comment: _Is cluster index is sparse or dense_ it depends on the data in the index. Often it is dense because people often create the clustered index on a uniqu value. _Is there any difference between sparse index and dense clustering index_ sparse and dense index are obviously opposites. How dense a clustered index is depends on the data. There is no rule that a clustered index is dense or sparse. These questions seems a bit abstract and not overly relevant to real world issues.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid If we are making cluster index on unique value then for each unique value there would be an entry in index file. And that entry would point to first occurrence of search key in database file. Then how it is dense I think it should be sparse. Suppose we have (1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4). We create index for (1,2,3,4) then it would be sparse not dense.

Comment: 1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,4 is not unique though

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid We do clustering for non key and non key could be repetitive. But our database file should be sorted on non key. So for (1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,4) we can do clustering index. In that case search key for index file would be(1,2,3,4) and this is I think would be sparse not dense. Correct me if I am wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

clustering/Nonclustering depends on physical organization of records based on some attribute (Search key)value and index entry.If index entry and physical organization of records are based on the same attribute it is a clustering index else nonclustering index.
Dense and sparse is based on the index entry. If for every value(first occurence) of search key(attribute) in the sequential file,there is one index entry then it is dense else if for some search key values there in one index entry then it is spase index.
In the given example index entry is dept.name and search key of file is also dept.name,so it is clustering index.Then for every value (first occurence) there is one index entry,so dense clustering index.